# How can I use `df.shift(n)` in pandas dataframe such that I can bring `n` item from bottom to the top instead of `nan` values or vice versa?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, shift

I have a pandas dataframe `df` containing 5 rows and 2 columns.

```
A   B
0   10  0
1   20  5
2   30  10
3   40  15
4   50  20
```

`df.to_dict()` returns

```
{'A': {0: 10, 1: 20, 2: 30, 3: 40, 4: 50},
 'B': {0: 0, 1: 5, 2: 10, 3: 15, 4: 20}}
```

For column A, I want to shift each item to two rows below. Instead of having `nan` values on top, I want to bring two elements that would be pushed out in the bottom to the top.

For column B, I want to do the opposite - shift each item to two rows above. Instead of having `nan` values on bottom, I want to bring two elements that would be pushed out in the top to the bottom.

I can use `df["A"].shift(2)` and `df["B"].shift(-2)`. However, I get nan values.

My expected results is:

```
A   B
0   40  10
1   50  15
2   10  20
3   20  0
4   30  5
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`numpy.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) instead `shift`:

```
df['A'] = np.roll(df["A"], 2)
df['B'] = np.roll(df["B"], -2)
print (df)
    A   B
0  40  10
1  50  15
2  10  20
3  20   0
4  30   5
```